# Trigger the counter function on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `keyup` function to calculate the number of words and characters. The function is working fine but when the page loads, initially it does not calculate the default values within the `textarea` and when any key is pressed then it works fine. I need to trigger the function on page load and calculate the default string `This is default text`. Here is my code below:

```
<p> Words <span id="count1">0</span></p>
<p>Characters <span id="count2">0</span></p>
<textarea rows="5" id="mycounter">This is default text</textarea>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mycounter").on("keyup", function () {
            var wcounts = 0;
            var ccounts = 0;

            if ((this.value.match(/\S+/g)) != null) {
                wcounts = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
            }
            if ((this.value.match(/\S+/g)) != null) {
                ccounts = this.value.length;
            }
            $('#count1').text(wcounts);
            $('#count2').text(ccounts);
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**trigger**](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to do it

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#mycounter").on("keyup", function () {
            var wcounts = 0;
            var ccounts = 0;

            if ((this.value.match(/\S+/g)) != null) {
                wcounts = this.value.match(/\S+/g).length;
            }
            if ((this.value.match(/\S+/g)) != null) {
                ccounts = this.value.length;
            }
            $('#count1').text(wcounts);
            $('#count2').text(ccounts);
        });
        $("#mycounter").trigger('keyup');
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Words <span id="count1">0</span></p>
<p>Characters <span id="count2">0</span></p>
<textarea rows="5" id="mycounter">This is default text</textarea>
```